# DNS no longer works after server reboot

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, uptime

Strangely enough, when I reboot my Ubuntu 12.04 server, the DNS no longer works, which makes the domain unavailable to access to my site. Normally the DNS should be working after a reboot, but this doesn't happen anymore. I use nginx to serve content, but nginx is already configured to work with my domains.

What are the typical practises must I do after a reboot and how can I solve this issue I experience? I already have BIND, networking and resolvconf to boot when the server boots up.

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> mysite.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

This is my output with `dig`

```
$ttl 38400
mysite.com.    IN    SOA    ns1.mysite.com. webmaster.mysite.com. (
            1055026205
            6H
            1H
            5D
            20M )
mysite.com.        IN    A     xx.xx.xx.xx # Server IP 
*.mysite.com.          IN    A     xx.xx.xx.xx # Server IP 
www.mysite.com.    IN    CNAME mysite.com.
ns1.mysite.com.    IN    A     xx.xx.xx.xx # Server 2nd IP
ns2.mysite.com.    IN    A     xx.xx.xx.xx # Server 3rd IP 
mysite.com.        IN    NS    ns1.mysite.com.
mysite.com.        IN    NS    ns2.mysite.com.
mail.mysite.com.   IN    MX    1 mysite.com.
```

This is the contents of /etc/resolv.conf

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 85.17.150.123
nameserver 85.17.96.69
nameserver 62.212.64.122
search localdomain
```

After using more `dig` commands, outputs:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.7.3-P3 <<>> @85.17.150.123 mysite.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 24847
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mysite.com.            IN  A

;; Query time: 2145 msec
;; SERVER: 85.17.150.123#53(85.17.150.123)
;; WHEN: Mon Nov  5 16:31:32 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 30
```

---

```
; <<>> DiG 9.7.3-P3 <<>> @85.17.96.69 mysite.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 27879
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mysite.com.            IN  A

;; Query time: 949 msec
;; SERVER: 85.17.96.69#53(85.17.96.69)
;; WHEN: Mon Nov  5 16:32:59 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 30
```

---

```
; <<>> DiG 9.7.3-P3 <<>> @62.212.64.122 mysite.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 29293
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mysite.com.            IN  A

;; Query time: 825 msec
;; SERVER: 62.212.64.122#53(62.212.64.122)
;; WHEN: Mon Nov  5 16:33:39 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 30
```

With Google DNS (8.8.8.8):

```
; <<>> DiG 9.7.3-P3 <<>> @8.8.8.8 mysite.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 38498
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mysite.com.            IN  A

;; Query time: 3982 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Mon Nov  5 16:37:27 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 30
```

Comment: What do you mean by "DNS no longer works"? `named` doesn't start? The resolver configuration is wrong? Errors/Log files? Do you know what steps are necessary to manually fix the issue?

Comment: @ChrisS I don't know how to explain "no longer works", this is what I'm asking about what should I normally check out for when doing a reboot. I don't know where to start from.

Comment: I take your point, but you know more than you've said.  Clearly you've done **something**, and it hasn't worked as you expected, to make you conclude that "DNS no longer works".  What did you do?  What did you expect?  What did you, in fact, see?  Please don't make us pull these data out of you like recalcitrant teeth; tell us what you know!  And as a personal request, the DNS is a public service; I find it much easier to read these questions when they're **not** redacted.

Comment: @BurningtheCodeigniter You clearly are trying to do something and it isn't working, what is that?? You've said something equivalent to "I can't drive my car", which could mean anything from "It was stolen", "I don't know how to drive", "The car doesn't start", to "The tire fell off". Each would have very different solutions.

Comment: @MadHatter Honestly, I haven't done much. I only added my bind rules (which I have pasted above) and rebooted my server, I have the domain configured from GoDaddy which was fine when I accessed the domain until I added the rules with BIND on my server after the reboot.

Comment: Post-edit: better, but not much.  You still haven't said what you did to get the output above (it wasn't just `dig`, I'm fairly sure of that), nor what you expected.

Comment: @MadHatter Which output? `dig` was called on my side on Terminal not on the server side. I copied the bind rules from `/var/lib/bind/mysite.com.hosts`

Comment: What is the content of your `/etc/resolv.conf` ?

Comment: @gparent updated post.

Comment: BtC, this question is starting to clock up close votes, because at the moment we can't help you.  Please, calm down, and edit your question as follows: "I rebooted my server.  When it came back, I typed $FOO, and I got as a result $BAR.  I was expecting $BAZ.  This makes me think that DNS is broken.  What is wrong?", substituting for $FOO, $BAR, and $BAZ appropriately.  Then we might at least understand the problem.  And if humanly possible, stop substituting "mysite.com" for your real domain.

Comment: What happens when you type `dig @85.17.150.123 mysite.com`, `dig @85.17.96.69 mysite.com`, `dig @62.212.64.122 mysite.com`? Which ones work, which ones do not?

Comment: @gparent Pasted my outputs.

Comment: Try `dig @8.8.8.8 mysite.com`

Comment: @gparent Updated again.

Comment: Are you hosted at a VPS provider? I'd try contacting them, I'm a bit confused as to why your stuff stopped working. You still don't want to give us the domain name (big mistake) so I don't know what else to do to help.

Comment: I am hosted at Leaseweb on a dedicated server. My URL: http://goo.gl/eTMqG

Answer (score 1):

Your domain is no longer being served.

If you do the following: `dig NS domosite.com`, you will notice that the response is `NXDOMAIN`:

```
gp@tin:~$ dig NS domosite.com

; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> NS domosite.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 51568
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;domosite.com.                  IN      NS

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
com.                    865     IN      SOA     a.gtld-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 1352133919 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Nov  5 16:46:12 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 103

gp@tin:~$
```

The root servers of the internet do not have the information necessary about your domain to answer your DNS queries, or it has expired and thus is no longer being resolved.

Make sure that your domain name is still active with your registrar, and verify the config on their end.

Note that this doesn't explain why Google's DNS servers refused to answer you. I have no idea why that is happening. There *could* be a firewall intercepting DNS requests, but even on the public internet your domain is unresponsive.

Note: The output to my query above is still NXDOMAIN if I use Google's DNS server on the dig command.

Comment: The domain does not expire until 2014.

Comment: Then maybe you didn't configure the nameservers correctly on the registrar's website. Something is clearly wrong here.

Comment: The nameservers are configured at the registrar - however I have raised an issue to the server team, they said http://i.imgur.com/osjC4.png. How would I configure this?

Comment: It looks like they're saying you don't have the proper interfaces configured on the server itself (Which might explain why your outbound connections are having various degrees of success.) you would probably set this in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't make head nor tail or that goo.gl URL above, but assuming that gparent's right about the actual domain name being domosite.com, the registrar is `theblackcow.ca`.  Their whois is hopelessly broken, but their [WHOIS website](http://theblackcow.ca/Whois.aspx) says that the nameservers are `DNS.YOURDOMAINHASEXPIRED.COM`
and `DNS2.YOURDOMAINHASEXPIRED.COM`, and moreover that the domain expired on 14/9/2012.

If that's the domain you're trying to make work, then that's the problem.

Comment: The domain does not expire until 2014.